# windows 8.1 winjs app, share image from web url

Tags: image, windows-8.1, winjs

I have a requirement where i have to share the images from the web url .I want to use this image in my app share contract. For this I am following the tutorial at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh758305.aspx). Only issue is that in the tutorial, file is selected using filePicker.Can you please provide any points on sharing the image from the url instead of file picker ?